# Connect to MySQL remotely with C#

Tags: c#, mysql, xampp

I have an assignment for IT at school, where I need to collect data for a database.

I made a C# app that allows user input, then stores it into mt database, problem being I can't seem to get it to connect.

I have a DNS: `maliciouzzhd.ddns.net`.

I have port `3306` open, and forwarded.

I just don't know what to do after this.

I am using XAMPP.

Here is my code:

```
string CommandText = $"INSERT INTO UserData (FirstName, LastName, BirthDay, BirthMonth, BirthYear, UserName, EMail, Password, Admin, IP) values ('{FirstNameInput.Text}', '{LastNameInput.Text}', {BirthDayInput.Text}, '{BirthMonthInput.Text}', {BirthYearInput.Text}, '{UserNameInput.Text}', '{EMailInput.Text}', '{PasswordInput1.Text}', 0, '{IPTextBox.Text}')";

string ConnectionString = "server=maliciouzzhd.ddns.net;database=***********;uid=***********;pwd=**************;";
using (var mysqlconnection = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    mysqlconnection.Open();
    using (MySqlCommand cmd = mysqlconnection.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 300;
        cmd.CommandText = CommandText;
        object objValue = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    }
    mysqlconnection.Close();
}
```

If anyone knows what I can do to get it to connect, that would be great.

Thanks

EDIT: Forgot to mention that this works on localhost, when I change `Server=maliciouzzhd.ddns.net` to `Server=10.0.0.1` or `Server=127.0.0.1`, but I need it to be remote.

Comment: What error are you receiving?

Comment: `Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.`

Comment: You need first to connect using ang GUI tool. If this fail then the issue is on the port forwarded you did create. Maybe it is not correctly configure.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I got it working on localhost

Comment: MySQL user that you are using may not be configured to login from "any" remote host.  MySQL users go like this `username@host`.  You create a user with `username@'%'` and try connecting.

Comment: I made a new account, but it still doesn't work :/

Answer (score 0):

First of a add the mysql library.
Project->Add Reference->Browse the dll file.
then import the class by using

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
```

MySql Connection code :

```
MySqlConnection conn;
conn = new MySqlConnection("SERVER=server_name;DATABASE=database_name;UID=database_username;PASSWORD=database_password");
```

to open connection

```
conn.Open();
```

to close connection

```
conn.Close();
```